# Is that Greyback's son that's killed?

Tags: character, predator-2

Is the Yautja that's the main antagonist in *Predator 2*, and ends up killed by Mike Harrigan, the son of [Greyback](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Greyback) (the leader of the Yautja at the end of the film)? Because when all the other Yautja are walking past him, it's like they're consoling him and he keeps acknowledging them by bowing his head.

Comment: Adding a random wiki link to a throwaway sentence is *not* proper context. I've turned it into a proper question and reopened it, though. Having seen the film is obviously not enough to understand the original question (comprised of a single sentence, not including the drunk ramblings) since not everyone is on top of every weird fan-fiction name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no suggestion from any canon source that City Hunter was Greyback's offspring. Greyback is an Elder Yautja, explaining the interaction between the other Yautja and Greyback.

The original script even had Greyback killing City Hunter. https://screenrant.com/prey-2-movie-predator-legacy-character-greyback-return/